# Cannot import settings in Django

Tags: python, django, pytest

I need to test my Django app with py.test. Hence, I need to tell py.test which is Django's settings module. The command I use for py.test is: `~/GitHub/django-training$ py.test --ds=training.settings`

Unfortunately, I get this error: `ERROR: Could not import settings 'training.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named training.settings`

Is looks very odd, because my folder structure looks like this:

```
django-training
    training
        settings.py
```

and my `sys.path` contains the `/home/user/GitHub/django-training` entry on the first position.

Now, why can't I use that settings file?

Comment: has `training` the `__init__.py`?

Comment: @lalo, sure, `training` contains the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: have you tried to import the settings handly?

Comment: init file... have to got this in your folder directory?

Comment: Give us your project structure.

Comment: if django-training has a __init__ file, you could try django-training.training.settings

Comment: @lalo, yes, I open a Python interpreter at the same path, do a `from training import settings` and no error occurs.

Comment: @GlynJackson I have the `__init__.py` file in the project (`training`) and app folder. So, not in `django-training`, because Django doesn't require it do be there.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I've pasted the basic structure of my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The training directory is probably really not on sys.path.  A usual approach is to run in a virtualenv and run `pip install -e .` in the `django-training` directory, assuming it has a `setup.py`.  But any other means which fits with your development workflow is fine.

Comment: You were right, this was the problem. I've put `training` in the path and it finds the settings file now. Thank you!