# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is defined, project settings do import via `python manage.py `, yet django-pytest does not find the django settings

Tags: python, django, pytest

### Synopsis of problem:

I want to use django-pytest to test my django scripts yet py.test complains that it cannot find DJANGO_MODULE_SETTINGS. I have followed the documentation of django-pytest for setting DJANGO_MODULE_SETTINGS. I am not getting the expected behavior from py.test.

I would like help troubleshooting this problem. *Thank you in advance.*

### References—[django-pytest documentation](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuring_django.html#the-environment-variable-django-settings-module)

#### Setting the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in virtualevn postactivate script:

1. In a new shell, the $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is not set.

   **I expect that the $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE would be None. It
   is.**

   ```
      In: echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
      Out:
   ```
2. Contents of `.virtualenv/browsing/bin/postactivate`

   **As documented in the django-pytest documents, one may set
   $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE by exporting it in the postactivate
   script for virutalenv.**

   ```
   export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=automated_browsing.settings
   ```
3. At terminal cli:

   **As expected, $DJANGO_SETTING_MODULE is defined.**

   ```
   # activate the virtualenv
   In: workon browsing
   In: echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
   Out: automated_browsing.settings
   ```

   **As expected, the settings module is set as shown when the server runs**:

   ```
    # cd into django project
    In: cd ../my_django/automated_browsing
    # see if server runs
    In: python manage.py runserver
    Out: # output
      Validating models...

      0 errors found
      September 02, 2014 - 10:45:35
      Django version 1.6.6, using settings 'automated_browsing.settings'
      Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
      Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
    In: ^C
   ```

   **As NOT expected, py.test cannot find it.**

   ```
      In: echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
      Out: automated_browsing.settings
      In: py.test tests/test_browser.py
      Out: …
       _pytest.config.UsageError: Could not import settings 
      'automated_browsing.settings'
      (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?)
      No module named automated_browsing.settings
   ```

### installed packages

1. Django==1.6.6
2. EasyProcess==0.1.6
3. PyVirtualDisplay==0.1.5
4. South==1.0
5. argparse==1.2.1
6. ipython==2.2.0
7. lxml==3.3.6
8. psycopg2==2.5.4
9. py==1.4.23
10. pytest-django==2.6.2
11. pytest==2.6.1
12. selenium==2.42.1
13. test-pkg==0.0
14. wsgiref==0.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem today. In the project/settings/ you have to create **init**.py . Like this django recognize the folder.

In my case I just typed **__inti__.py** which was wrong. I corrected **inti**.py --> **init**.py and it works fine.

Hope it helps.
V.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638858/cannot-import-settings-in-django?rq=1), I have solved my problem.

According to the [django-pytest documentation for managing the python path](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managing_python_path.html#automatic-looking-for-of-django-projects):

> By default, pytest-django tries to find Django projects by
>   automatically looking for the project’s manage.py file and adding its
>   directory to  the Python path.

I assumed that executing `py.test tests/test_browser.py` inside of the django project containing `manage.py` would handle the PYTHONPATH. This was an incorrect assumption in my situation.

I added the following to `.virtualenv/$PROJECT/bin/postactivate`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/development/my_python/my_django/automated_browsing
```

And now py.test works as expected.